# Prove a combinatoric identity

Tags: combinatorics

Prove the following identity for all $0\leq r\leq n,m$:

$${{n+m}\choose{r}}={n\choose0}{m\choose r}+{n\choose1}{m\choose{r-1}}+\cdots+{n\choose{r-1}}{m\choose1}+{n\choose r}{m\choose0}$$

Progress:

${n+m}\choose{r}$ $=$ $\sum\limits_{i=0}^r$$n\choose{i}$$m\choose{r-i}$
If Pascal's Triangle is applicable here, I don't see how yet.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you are interested in combinatorial proofs, but if you are, here it is: how do you pick a group of $r$ persons from a group of $m$ men and $n$ women? There are $r+1$ possibilities:

- you pick $r$ men and $0$ women;
- you pick $r-1$ men and one woman;
- …
- you pick $0$ men and $r$ women.

And you're done.

Comment: Why are there $r+1$ possibilities?

Comment: @SlavikEgorov The possible numbers of women are $0,1,2,\dots,r.$ How many numbers is that?

Comment: Because the number $k$ of men that you can pick belongs to $\{0,1,\ldots,r\}$ and for each such group of men the number of women that you can pick is exactly equal to $r-k$.